# Need to sum up number in a all rows of the table from a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 250 000 rows, one column has numeric values only, some of them have spaces between thousands and so like 1 000 and so one.

I would like to calculate the whole sum of the columns combined of 250 000 rows.

What would be the quickest for the script to run and return?

is it only a MySQL query or do I have to calculate with PHP?

Have no clue where to start.

Comment: `if (!$code) {print "Where's your code?";}`

Comment: Is your field containing the numbers in `int` format? If not, what format is it in?

Comment: SELECT SUM(CONVERT(name_of_column),UNSIGNED INTEGER))
FROM table_name;

Comment: No they are not int format numbers

Comment: @Pedro Lobito  -as i said: Have no clue where to start.

Comment: Corrected spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(REPLACE(my_column, ' ', '')) result
        FROM my_table";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['result'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to remove whitespaces, and then just [`sum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) the result. MySQL will implicitly convert the strings to numbers for you:

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(my_column, ' ', ''))
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: and how will i echo the result?

Comment: Do you know how to run a SQL query from PHP?

Comment: yes i know. But as this is new for me, then i dont really get how should i mysql_result look like